# I am trying to import json with html tags into my html. But it just shows up as huge string. I am using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to import the description object as html and not string. I tired removing the quotes, but that is not problem. I also tried JSON.parse and JSON.stringify()

I have already imported it. In my code it is

```
<p>{state.jobs.description}</p>
```

**When I view it in my console it appears like this**

```
<p>
  "<p>What's next in music happens on SoundCloud first. As the world’s largest open audio platform, SoundCloud is powered by a connected community of creators, listeners and curators who share, discover and influence what’s new, now and next in music and audio.</p>\n<p>We are looking for an impact-driven Lead Data Scientist to solve and help others solve exciting problems across the SoundCloud product using Machine</p>"
<p>
```

**This the is json**

```
{
"description": "<p>What's next in music happens on SoundCloud first. As the world’s largest open audio platform, SoundCloud is powered by a connected community of creators, listeners and curators who share, discover and influence what’s new, now and next in music and audio.</p>\n<p>We are looking for an impact-driven Lead Data Scientist to solve and help others solve exciting problems across the SoundCloud product using Machine</p> "
}
```

[This is how it look on web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeA8s.png)

Comment: you forgot the most important thing. How do you import it?

Comment: How are you setting the HTML content of the `p` element?

Comment: You're inserting it as text (ie. textContent or innerText) try something like `document.getElementById('myTargetContainer').innerHTML = myJSON.description;